# Routes and def to_param "#{self.id}-#{self.slug.parameterize}"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, routes, friendly-url, slug

I have **Routes.rb**

```
get 'students/area_aluno'
root 'home#index'
```

And in `Course.rb`:

```
def to_param
  "#{self.id}-#{self.slug.parameterize}"
end
```

On Heroku, I am getting this error, because the pages haven't any ID. I don’t know hot to fix it nor do I know why it works on only `localhost`.

`to_param` is working for every model, however.

> Error -------------------------
>
> NoMethodError in Home#index
>
> Showing /app/app/views/home/index.html.erb where line #90 raised:
>
> undefined method `slug' for #
>
> Extracted source (around line #30):
>
> def to_param
>       "#{self.id}-#{self.slug.parameterize}"    end
>
> end

Comment: Looks like your Course model doesn't have `slug` attribute on Heroku. If you ssh into Heroku rails console, what is the output of `Course.last.slug`?

Comment: maybe you forgot to run db migrations? also you don't need "self.id" or "self.slug", it's just "id" and "slug"; only when you're _writing_ an attribute (self.name = 'bob')